# move along/replace certain rows csv python

Tags: python, csv

i have a csv file for a quiz which goes as follows

```
name,score1,score2,score3,highest,avg
foo,4,10,7,10,10.3
bar,6,4,9,9,6.3
baz,8,4,6,8,6
```

my question is, how do i go about moving the scores one left when *foo* next takes the quiz, with score 1 being replaced by the score from said test and score 3 being deleted, also updating highest and avg. I've tried many different ways but I can't figure this out

EDIT:

post-modification, say foo scored 6 and baz scored 2, i'd want the file to say

```
foo,6,4,10,10,3.6
baz,2,8,4,8,4.6
```

I tried appending the rows to a dictionary, but couldn't figure out how to modify the scores independently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't provide any of your code as a starting point it's a little harder to help you.  The following code will take a CSV, check through the names and scores in the first column and update the corresponding row with the new score:

```
import csv

def update_scores(name, new_score):
    new_file = []    # This will hold our information for later (since we can't both read and write simultaneously)
    with open('scores.csv', 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for line in reader:
            if line[0] == name:    # We have found the row that matches the name we put in
                highest = max(int(new_score), int(line[1]), int(line[2]))   # Form the new highest score
                avg = round((int(new_score) + int(line[1]) + int(line[2])) / 3.00, 2)    # Form the new average score
                new_file.append([line[0], new_score, line[1], line[2], highest, avg])    # Write all of this new information to our new_file
            else:
                new_file.append(line)    # If the line doesn't need to be updated, just add it to our new_file

    with open('scores.csv', 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for line in new_file:    # Write all of our new information back into the new file.
            writer.writerow(line)

update_scores('foo', '4')   # Send in the name and it's newest score
```

Answer (score 0):

I am confused by how you are calculating averages. 10.3 is not the average of 4, 10, and 7, for example. For my answer I am assuming you just want the average of the three scores:

```
import csv

def update_scores(new_scores):
    rows = []
    with open('quiz.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        next(reader)        
        for row in reader:
            if row[0] in new_scores:
                updated_scores = [new_scores[row[0]], int(row[1]), int(row[2])]
                highest = max(updated_scores)
                avg = sum(updated_scores) / float(len(updated_scores))
                rows.append([row[0]] + updated_scores + [highest, '%.1f' % avg])
            else:
                rows.append(row)
    with open('quiz.csv', 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(['name','score1','score2','score3','highest','avg'])
        writer.writerows(rows)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    new_scores = {'foo': 6, 'baz': 2}
    update_scores(new_scores)
```

Ouput:

```
name,score1,score2,score3,highest,avg
foo,6,4,10,10,6.7
bar,6,4,9,9,6.3
baz,2,8,4,8,4.7
```